# Un-fulfilled reference listing

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a simple way (i.e not inspecting the output of a processing run) to get a list of un-fulfilled references?

As in, if i reference something

```
\ref{SomethingReallyCoolIHaventThoughtOfYet}
```

And I continue writing, is there a clean way of getting a list;

```
LineNo:SomethingReallyCoolIHaventThoughtOfYet
LineNo:SomethingElseIAlreadyForgotAbout
```

If those references don't point to anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be the following in a terminal window:

(Mac or Linux)

```
$ grep Reference mytexfile.log
```

(Windows)

```
$ findstr Reference mytexfile.log
```

and this will produce the relevant list.